# while opening VS code it is throwing error saying " Unable to write program user data"

Tags: command-line, apt, unity, system-installation, upgrade

Screenshot of the dialog box which comes while opening VSCode:

[image: screenshot of the dialog box which comes while opening vs code.]

my question is about vscode error after the new update of ubuntu.

Comment: What new update your question has no info about any update. From what to what?

Comment: check this out: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/510

Comment: Thanks @Cagri it worked.

Comment: @David the new update of ubuntu os 22.04 version i was talking about here.

Comment: Still does not give an answer UP from WHAT to WHAT and edit the question not a comment.

Comment: I got my answer and this dialog box itself saying what's the error i am asking about...and i guess it' enough.